# block incoming call without ringing even for fraction of a second android

Tags: android, phone-call

i have used the following code:

**Problem:**  It is working fine and blocking incoming call but **phone ring for fraction of a second before disconnect the call**. can there be a solution which i am looking for .

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
        Bundle b = intent.getExtras();                     
        incomingNumber1 =   b.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context
                                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        Class c = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());    
        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(telephony);          
        telephonyService.endCall(); 
}}
```

I have not found the answer to the problem yet. I want solution which work perfectly on Android 2.3. Incoming call is to be blocked fully there must not any ring.

Comment: Is there any search operation? Or you are using same code as you have given?

Comment: I am not sure, m.invoke() might be doing. Try something other than this to get your service.

Comment: Did you find answer ?